# Wildfly 8 not starting in windows 7 32 bit

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8

I am starting to start Wildfly AS 8.2.0 on a Windows 7 32 bit machine but get the following error:

```
19:59:01,582 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.endpoint.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.endpoint.management: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found
at org.xnio.Xnio.doGetInstance(Xnio.java:238)
at org.xnio.Xnio.getInstance(Xnio.java:193)
at org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint(Remoting.java:112)
at org.jboss.as.remoting.ManagementEndpointService.createEndpoint(ManagementEndpointService.java:45)
at org.jboss.as.remoting.EndpointService.start(EndpointService.java:76)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its one of the xnio libraries missing. (I would have commented your post if I could, I just do not have enough reputation to do so.) Make sure to have everything needed in the classpath.

**EDIT:** Yes, thats the problem. Theres no XNIO provider in the cp